# slow file upload speed httpclient to spring mvc on glassfish

Tags: java, spring, performance, glassfish, apache-httpclient-4.x

So here's the situation: I am able to successfully upload a file from a java swing application to my glassfish 4 server running a spring web application.

**My problem is that it takes forever to upload!!!**  I understand that there are a lot of factors that goes into speed up/down on the web.  I just want to make sure that my code isn't the slow point!

For my test file of **1.7mb**, it takes on average about **14 seconds** to upload.  According to my ISP and verified by megapath speed test, i have a very consistent 50 MB/s connection both ways.

There seems to be a lot of different ways to achieve the same thing with respect to file uploads.  I'm more of a UI developer and file xfer is new for me... I had a hard enough time getting the upload process to work.. i'm stumped on where to begin to troubleshoot/optimize this.

I've included the code that sends the file from the client as well as the  the relevant method in the spring controller that handles the incoming file.  (please note that I am sending meta data about the file in the form of JSON along with the file)

**(client code, using apache's http client libraries)**

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

// request bean to JSON string
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String requestBeanAsJSON = mapper.writeValueAsString( requestBeanToSend );

HttpPost outgoingPostRequest = new HttpPost( serverURL );

FileBody fileBody = new FileBody( fileToSend, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY );
StringBody stringBody1 = new StringBody( "msg", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA );

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
builder.addPart( "upfile", fileBody );
builder.addPart( "text1", stringBody1 );
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

outgoingPostRequest.setEntity( entity );

CloseableHttpResponse responseBody = httpclient.execute( outgoingPostRequest );


long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println( "completed in " + ((end-start)/1000) + " seconds.");
```

**(server code, spring, glassfish4)**

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "up" )
public @ResponseBody MyReturnObject handleFileUpload( @RequestParam( "file" ) MultipartFile file )
{
    try
    {

         BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( new File( FtConstants.getTempUploadBaseDir() + File.separator + uniqueToken + "." + FileUtils.getFileExtension( file.getOriginalFilename() ) ) ) );
            FileCopyUtils.copy( file.getInputStream(), stream );
            stream.close();

    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {

    }

    MyReturnObject returnObject = new MyReturnObject();
    returnObject.setToken(  RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric( 16 ));
    return returnObject;
}
```

Is there anything glaring that I'm doing wrong?  Like I said above, it works, but it's wicked slow.

Comment: Why are you using a `BufferedOutputStream` to copy the file? Can't you do only `FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream("theCopiedFile.txt"));` or simply the `copy(byte[] in, File out)`   method?

Comment: @Jaumzera - That will hardly make any difference.

Comment: @Stephen C, according to my tests here, it takes something around 500ms (average) for a BufferedOuputStream to copy a 214MB-file while it takes 50ms to the same copy using a non-buffered alternative. I think 10x is something relevant. Doesn't it? Considering my hardware specifications, of course.

Comment: @Jaumzera - There is something very odd about that.  If your "non-buffered alternative" using memory mapped file buffers?  Please provide details of how you are testing.  (According to my understanding, the worst that an unnecessary BufferedOutputStream would do is to add an extra memory -> memory copy.  It is not plausible that gives a 10 x performance hit ...)

Comment: @StephenC http://pastebin.com/AcwdGDWn

Comment: @Jaumzera - I'm still surprised.  But I suspect that part of the reason for >>your<< 10 x speedup  is down to >>you<< writing to "/tmp" ... which is a RAM backed file system.  In a normal FS, the disk writes would slow down the transfer rate ... and reduce the relative speedup.

Comment: But anyway, if you do the sums, you are saving 0.002 seconds per MB copied.  If he got the same savings in his problem, he would get 0.004 seconds speed up.  That is orders of magnitude too small to be relevant to >>his<< situation.

Comment: @StephenC Done! The results were: 1 Non-buffered copy: 80, Buffered copy: 657. 2 Non-buffered copy: 74, Buffered copy: 584. 3 Non-buffered copy: 75, Buffered copy: 603. 4 Non-buffered copy: 75, Buffered copy: 603. 5 Non-buffered copy: 75, Buffered copy: 583.

Comment: @StephenC it's not /tmp anymore

Comment: Even so.  For the reasons I stated above, I think it is unlikely that your optimization will make a measurable difference for the OP.

Comment: @StephenC My point is: there's no reason to use a stream. Do you agree?

Comment: @Jaumzera - My point is: your suggested optimization is unlikely to help.  Do you agree?

Comment: @StephenC then... correcting my suggestion isn't either. Hu?

Comment: Incorrect.  Advising the OP (and others) that fiddling around with the streams is unlikely to make >>his<< download go appreciably faster will save him time and disappointment.  This is all about context.  In other contexts your suggestion will help.  In this case, it probably won't.

Comment: @StephenC, ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything glaring that I'm doing wrong?

Since you asked ... this is glaringly wrong!  It squashes and and all exceptions (apart from `Error` and its subclasses).

```
catch( Exception e )
{

}
```

Note that this won't affect the transfer rate, but it could conceal various operational problems ... and bugs.

I can't see any problem in the code that would affect transfer rates.  I would start investigating using CPU and network performance tools.

Comment: stephen c:  thanks for the comment... i had to remove some corporate specific code and left that catch in there for completeness only...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything glaring that I'm doing wrong?

The following looks suspect to me:

In the client you create the file part of the multipart upload via:

```
builder.addPart( "upfile", fileBody );
```

but the controller is looking for:

```
@RequestParam( "file" )
```

instead of

```
@RequestParam( "upfile")
```

I suspect, as has been pointed out above, you're swallowing the exception being thrown and returning the dummy random response. Have you checked to see if the file has actually been uploaded?

Comment: thanks! didn't notice that difference, but the files are uploaded, and then I can download them and verify their hashes to ensure i'm getting what I'm expecting...